# GEE interpretation

Tags: r, generalized-estimating-equations

I'm new to stats, but I'm working with an SPSS guy. I'm more of an R person. I got R to run the GEE my partner suggested we use without any errors, however my output looks completely different from what my partner expected. He said we need to report our wald chi squared scores and p values. This is the output I got:

```
Coefficients:
                                Estimate  Naive S.E.   Naive z  Robust S.E.
(Intercept)                    12.0113780   2.176266  5.5192610   1.7172839
GroupSP                         3.4065444   1.915380  1.7785216   1.3600899
GroupWT                         7.5666147   3.058349  2.4740844   2.1980965
GroupWW                         0.5340392   2.192882  0.2435331   1.4431915
Group_type_at_weaned_ageSUM    -3.1602746   2.642772 -1.1958181   1.3461348
Group_type_at_weaned_ageUMM    -2.8708954   2.094266 -1.3708364   1.7819845
Group_type_at_weaned_ageUUM    13.3411979        NaN        NaN   5.1915457
Mother_parityP                 -1.4962279   2.127058 -0.7034259   1.7714872
YL_availability_at_weaned_age   0.3257546   1.849264  0.1761536   1.3810758
Infant_sexM                     1.0382193   1.622102  0.6400457   0.9977027
Infant_sexU                   -13.2409090   3.242163 -4.0839738   1.4520145
                               Robust z
(Intercept)                    6.9944045
GroupSP                        2.5046465
GroupWT                        3.4423488
GroupWW                        0.3700404
Group_type_at_weaned_ageSUM   -2.3476657
Group_type_at_weaned_ageUMM   -1.6110665
Group_type_at_weaned_ageUUM    2.5697930
Mother_parityP                -0.8446168
YL_availability_at_weaned_age  0.2358702
Infant_sexM                    1.0406099
Infant_sexU                   -9.1189920
```

Where am I getting wald chi squared scores and p values out of this?

Answer (score 2):

The Wald $\chi^2$ test statistics are just the squares of the $z$ test statistics you have in the R output. In this case, the $P$-values will should be the same. Unfortunately, I cannot advise as to whether you should use the Naive z or Robust z.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to use the Robust Z as it uses the Huber-White Sandwich estimator.